# Populate a html tag like <h2> from AEM dialog

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm trying to allow an author to change the heading size in the markup based on a dropdown in the dialog with the options "h1, h2, h3, h4".  If none is selected, it should default to h2.

I'm trying to do this with ternary code like I would for dynamic classes or content, but when I do this it just prints the code out on the page.  The result of the following should be `<h2> Heading </h2>` or have h2 replaced by a dialog selection

```
<${properties.headingSize ? properties.headingSize : 'h2'}>
    ${properties.heading}
</${properties.headingSize ? properties.headingSize : 'h2'}>
```

The result of this code in Inspect Element is

```
<${properties.headingSize ? properties.headingSize :="h2" }>Heading <!--${properties.headingSize-->
```

Is this not a recommended way to accomplish dynamic markup?  Or is there a way to get the ternary to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way to solve your problem is to make use of the `data-sly-element` statement to replace your element name. Sample usage is shown below.

```
<h2 data-sly-element="${properties.headingSize || 'h2'}">${properties.heading}</h2>
```

For more information on the acceptable values for `data-sly-element` as well as the  available block statements that can be used in HTL, kindly refer [this official documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/block-statements.html)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an <a> tag?  i.e. If ${properties.link} is filled in the dialog then the tag is <a>, otherwise its a <div>?  What to do with the `href` in that situation is tripping me up.

Comment: @VirgeAssault You can use `data-sly-attribute` to use the attribute. If the value for the attribute is null or empty it won't add the attribute to the element. Alternatively, you can just use `data-sly-test` to either display a `div` tag or an anchor tag.